# TypeError in simple registration/login program

Tags: python, list, append

For practice purposes I tried coding a little registration/login system which stores the registered users' data in a list.

I tried to solve this by getting user input (name, nickname and password), then create a list with the chosen "Name" which then stores "Nickname" and "PW" . This then should be then stored in the created list "users" which is being created in the beginning.

So I would have a list with different names/persons which includes their data.

The problem is that in the else statement it won't let me create the name-variable list with (username, password) in it. "TypeError: string indices must be integers"

```
users = []

def register():
    print("Please insert your Name")
    name = input()
    print("Please insert your Username")
    username = input()
    print("Please type your Password")
    userpw = input()
    
    if name in users:
        print("Account already exist, try again")
        register()
    else:
        users.append(name[username, userpw])
```

Comment: Change `users = {}` and at the end, `users[name] = [username, userpw]`

Comment: Python doesn't have named lists. If you want to store keyed data use a dict.

Comment: @arsho Thank you very much. This helped me a lot and I even managed to get the whole Program done by now.

Answer (score 0):

This code creates a dictionary for a user and then check if its already registrated. I recommend using some sort of database to avoid dataloss from program restarts.

```
users = []


def register():
    print("Please insert your Name")
    name = input()
    print("Please insert your Username")
    username = input()
    print("Please type your Password")
    userpw = input()

    for x in users:
        if x['name'] == name:
            print("Account already exist, try again")
            register()
            return

    user = {'name': name,
            'username': username,
            'password': userpw}

    users.append(user)
```